Can't boot from live USB after attempted 24.04 upgrade
After attempting to upgrade to 22.04 from 20.04 on a Asus VivoBook I'm getting a black screen only showing
dev/sda2: clean, 552599/6111232 files, 7119295/24414464 blocks

and a blinking cursor. I've created a live USB stick from which I was hoping to fix the system but that doesn't boot even though I've checked the BIOS setup that the system would boot up from USB. Attempting to connect wirelessly via CLI and updating the system by command line doesn't work as the NetworkManager fails systemctl status NetworkManager.service.
How can I restore the system?

okay i dont know what bios/manufacturer you have but you can google. from mine i have an msi and i were able to press f11 to select to boot the usb instead of windows. i also changed the boot order and priority too. these days its becoming common for a bios to sport that option but it could be a different key for your manufacturer. i hope that helps sometimes you're able to toggle to select which device you wish to boot from during boot by pressing a key.

The hotkey for Asus is ESC which is stated on the page which I mentioned above but forgot to mention. From choosing the USB stick (ubuntu (P2: Sandisk SD9...)) I go to a black screen with dev/sda2: clean, ... => splashscreen => dev/sda2: clean, ... blinking cursor.

i would suggest re flashing the usb drive with other software like balena etcher, there was an issue i had with rufus which initially worked but flashing with other software resolved it.

I've got three usb drives which I've used Balena etcher and then Startup Disk Creator. None of them work.

With the latest usb drive I've got an error sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] No caching mode page found follwed by sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through. Going to check out what that means...

I managed to Boot to the live USB drive (just by chance) changing the boot order to first UEFI: SanDisk, Partition 2 and then ubuntu (P2: Sandisk SD9...). The boot failed first and then booted the ububtu partition. This is probably not how things are oppose to be but it works.

I had the same problem trying to upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 with a slight difference : my computer rebooted and I was able to log in. I then decided to install the USB wifi antenna driver (a Realtek device) the day after.
When I switched my computer on the day after, neither Ubuntu nor a 22.04 USB live key would load.
I attempted to change the BIOS parameters many times but nothing changed.
During one of these boot attempts, I accidentally pulled off the wifi USB key and the Ubuntu flash screen appeared.
I could then reinstall 22.04 and then decided to stay on that release.
Hope this helps!
